# Como pegar a ação do click no Year Calendar

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos

Bom dia !
Eu sou iniciante e estou com difículdades em pegar a ação do `Click` no meu Calendar.

https://www.bootstrap-year-calendar.com/#Examples/Full%20example

Preciso fazer exatamente este acima, mas no meu caso não estou conseguindo pegar as ações do click para cadastrar a data de um evento e etc.

Alguém poderia me ajudar por favor ?

ATÉ O MOMENTO ESTÁ ASSIM:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale = 1, shrink-tp-fit=no  ">
        <title>CALENDÁRIO OFICIAL</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugin/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/js-year-calendar@latest/dist/js-year-calendar.min.css" />

    </head>
    <body>




    <div data-provide="calendar"></div>




    </body>



    <script type="text/javascript" src="plugin/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="plugin/js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="plugin/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/js-year-calendar@latest/dist/js-year-calendar.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/js-year-calendar@latest/locales/js-year-calendar.pt.js"></script>


    <script>
    function editEvent(event) {
        $('#event-modal input[name="event-index"]').val(event ? event.id : '');
        $('#event-modal input[name="event-name"]').val(event ? event.name : '');
        $('#event-modal input[name="event-location"]').val(event ? event.location : '');
        $('#event-modal input[name="event-start-date"]').datepicker('update', event ? event.startDate : '');
        $('#event-modal input[name="event-end-date"]').datepicker('update', event ? event.endDate : '');
        $('#event-modal').modal();
    }

    function deleteEvent(event) {
        var dataSource = $('#calendar').data('calendar').getDataSource();

        for(var i in dataSource) {
            if(dataSource[i].id == event.id) {
                dataSource.splice(i, 1);
                break;
            }
        }

        $('#calendar').data('calendar').setDataSource(dataSource);
    }

    function saveEvent() {
        var event = {
            id: $('#event-modal input[name="event-index"]').val(),
            name: $('#event-modal input[name="event-name"]').val(),
            location: $('#event-modal input[name="event-location"]').val(),
            startDate: $('#event-modal input[name="event-start-date"]').datepicker('getDate'),
            endDate: $('#event-modal input[name="event-end-date"]').datepicker('getDate')
        }

        var dataSource = $('#calendar').data('calendar').getDataSource();

        if(event.id) {
            for(var i in dataSource) {
                if(dataSource[i].id == event.id) {
                    dataSource[i].name = event.name;
                    dataSource[i].location = event.location;
                    dataSource[i].startDate = event.startDate;
                    dataSource[i].endDate = event.endDate;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var newId = 0;
            for(var i in dataSource) {
                if(dataSource[i].id > newId) {
                    newId = dataSource[i].id;
                }
            }

            newId++;
            event.id = newId;

            dataSource.push(event);
        }

        $('#calendar').data('calendar').setDataSource(dataSource);
        $('#event-modal').modal('hide');
    }

    $(function() {
        var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();

        $('#calendar').calendar({
            enableContextMenu: true,
            enableRangeSelection: true,
            contextMenuItems:[
                {
                    text: 'Update',
                    click: editEvent
                },
                {
                    text: 'Delete',
                    click: deleteEvent
                }
            ],
            selectRange: function(e) {
                editEvent({ startDate: e.startDate, endDate: e.endDate });
            },
            mouseOnDay: function(e) {
                if(e.events.length > 0) {
                    var content = '';

                    for(var i in e.events) {
                        content += '<div class="event-tooltip-content">'
                                        + '<div class="event-name" style="color:' + e.events[i].color + '">' + e.events[i].name + '</div>'
                                        + '<div class="event-location">' + e.events[i].location + '</div>'
                                    + '</div>';
                    }

                    $(e.element).popover({
                        trigger: 'manual',
                        container: 'body',
                        html:true,
                        content: content
                    });

                    $(e.element).popover('show');
                }
            },
            mouseOutDay: function(e) {
                if(e.events.length > 0) {
                    $(e.element).popover('hide');
                }
            },
            dayContextMenu: function(e) {
                $(e.element).popover('hide');
            },
            dataSource: [
                {
                    id: 0,
                    name: 'Google I/O',
                    location: 'San Francisco, CA',
                    startDate: new Date(currentYear, 4, 28),
                    endDate: new Date(currentYear, 4, 29)
                },
                {
                    id: 1,
                    name: 'Microsoft Convergence',
                    location: 'New Orleans, LA',
                    startDate: new Date(currentYear, 2, 16),
                    endDate: new Date(currentYear, 2, 19)
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    name: 'Microsoft Build Developer Conference',
                    location: 'San Francisco, CA',
                    startDate: new Date(currentYear, 3, 29),
                    endDate: new Date(currentYear, 4, 1)
                },
                {
                    id: 3,
                    name: 'Apple Special Event',
                    location: 'San Francisco, CA',
                    startDate: new Date(currentYear, 8, 1),
                    endDate: new Date(currentYear, 8, 1)
                },
                {
                    id: 4,
                    name: 'Apple Keynote',
                    location: 'San Francisco, CA',
                    startDate: new Date(currentYear, 8, 9),
                    endDate: new Date(currentYear, 8, 9)
                },
                {
                    id: 5,
                    name: 'Chrome Developer Summit',
                    location: 'Mountain View, CA',
                    startDate: new Date(currentYear, 10, 17),
                    endDate: new Date(currentYear, 10, 18)
                },
                {
                    id: 6,
                    name: 'F8 2015',
                    location: 'San Francisco, CA',
                    startDate: new Date(currentYear, 2, 25),
                    endDate: new Date(currentYear, 2, 26)
                },
                {
                    id: 7,
                    name: 'Yahoo Mobile Developer Conference',
                    location: 'New York',
                    startDate: new Date(currentYear, 7, 25),
                    endDate: new Date(currentYear, 7, 26)
                },
                {
                    id: 8,
                    name: 'Android Developer Conference',
                    location: 'Santa Clara, CA',
                    startDate: new Date(currentYear, 11, 1),
                    endDate: new Date(currentYear, 11, 4)
                },
                {
                    id: 9,
                    name: 'LA Tech Summit',
                    location: 'Los Angeles, CA',
                    startDate: new Date(currentYear, 10, 17),
                    endDate: new Date(currentYear, 10, 17)
                }
            ]
        });

        $('#save-event').click(function() {
            saveEvent();
        });
    });

    </script>

    </html>
```

Comment: Coloque na pergunta o que já tentou fazer.

Comment: Mestre, coloquei lá ! Obrigado pela atenção desde já.

Answer (score 0):

Estava faltando adicionar o modal e os formulário com os campos

```js
function editEvent(event) {
        $('#event-modal input[name="event-index"]').val(event ? event.id : '');
        $('#event-modal input[name="event-name"]').val(event ? event.name : '');
        $('#event-modal input[name="event-location"]').val(event ? event.location : '');
        $('#event-modal input[name="event-start-date"]').datepicker('update', event ? event.startDate : '');
        $('#event-modal input[name="event-end-date"]').datepicker('update', event ? event.endDate : '');
        $('#event-modal').modal();
    }

    function deleteEvent(event) {
        var dataSource = $('#calendar').data('calendar').getDataSource();

        for(var i in dataSource) {
            if(dataSource[i].id == event.id) {
                dataSource.splice(i, 1);
                break;
            }
        }
        
        $('#calendar').data('calendar').setDataSource(dataSource);
    }

    function saveEvent() {
        var event = {
            id: $('#event-modal input[name="event-index"]').val(),
            name: $('#event-modal input[name="event-name"]').val(),
            location: $('#event-modal input[name="event-location"]').val(),
            startDate: $('#event-modal input[name="event-start-date"]').datepicker('getDate'),
            endDate: $('#event-modal input[name="event-end-date"]').datepicker('getDate')
        }
        
        var dataSource = $('#calendar').data('calendar').getDataSource();

        if(event.id) {
            for(var i in dataSource) {
                if(dataSource[i].id == event.id) {
                    dataSource[i].name = event.name;
                    dataSource[i].location = event.location;
                    dataSource[i].startDate = event.startDate;
                    dataSource[i].endDate = event.endDate;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var newId = 0;
            for(var i in dataSource) {
                if(dataSource[i].id > newId) {
                    newId = dataSource[i].id;
                }
            }
            
            newId++;
            event.id = newId;
        
            dataSource.push(event);
        }
        
        $('#calendar').data('calendar').setDataSource(dataSource);
        $('#event-modal').modal('hide');
    }

    $(function() {
        var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();

        $('#calendar').calendar({
            enableContextMenu: true,
            enableRangeSelection: true,
            language: 'pt',
            contextMenuItems:[
                {
                    text: 'Update',
                    click: editEvent
                },
                {
                    text: 'Delete',
                    click: deleteEvent
                }
            ],
            selectRange: function(e) {
                editEvent({ startDate: e.startDate, endDate: e.endDate });
            },
            mouseOnDay: function(e) {
                if(e.events.length > 0) {
                    var content = '';
                    
                    for(var i in e.events) {
                        content += '<div class="event-tooltip-content">'
                                        + '<div class="event-name" style="color:' + e.events[i].color + '">' + e.events[i].name + '</div>'
                                        + '<div class="event-location">' + e.events[i].location + '</div>'
                                    + '</div>';
                    }
                
                    $(e.element).popover({
                        trigger: 'manual',
                        container: 'body',
                        html:true,
                        content: content
                    });
                    
                    $(e.element).popover('show');
                }
            },
            mouseOutDay: function(e) {
                if(e.events.length > 0) {
                    $(e.element).popover('hide');
                }
            },
            dayContextMenu: function(e) {
                $(e.element).popover('hide');
            },
            dataSource: [
                {
                    id: 0,
                    name: 'Google I/O',
                    location: 'San Francisco, CA',
                    startDate: new Date(currentYear, 4, 28),
                    endDate: new Date(currentYear, 4, 29)
                },
                {
                    id: 1,
                    name: 'Microsoft Convergence',
                    location: 'New Orleans, LA',
                    startDate: new Date(currentYear, 2, 16),
                    endDate: new Date(currentYear, 2, 19)
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    name: 'Microsoft Build Developer Conference',
                    location: 'San Francisco, CA',
                    startDate: new Date(currentYear, 3, 29),
                    endDate: new Date(currentYear, 4, 1)
                },
                {
                    id: 3,
                    name: 'Apple Special Event',
                    location: 'San Francisco, CA',
                    startDate: new Date(currentYear, 8, 1),
                    endDate: new Date(currentYear, 8, 1)
                },
                {
                    id: 4,
                    name: 'Apple Keynote',
                    location: 'San Francisco, CA',
                    startDate: new Date(currentYear, 8, 9),
                    endDate: new Date(currentYear, 8, 9)
                },
                {
                    id: 5,
                    name: 'Chrome Developer Summit',
                    location: 'Mountain View, CA',
                    startDate: new Date(currentYear, 10, 17),
                    endDate: new Date(currentYear, 10, 18)
                },
                {
                    id: 6,
                    name: 'F8 2015',
                    location: 'San Francisco, CA',
                    startDate: new Date(currentYear, 2, 25),
                    endDate: new Date(currentYear, 2, 26)
                },
                {
                    id: 7,
                    name: 'Yahoo Mobile Developer Conference',
                    location: 'New York',
                    startDate: new Date(currentYear, 7, 25),
                    endDate: new Date(currentYear, 7, 26)
                },
                {
                    id: 8,
                    name: 'Android Developer Conference',
                    location: 'Santa Clara, CA',
                    startDate: new Date(currentYear, 11, 1),
                    endDate: new Date(currentYear, 11, 4)
                },
                {
                    id: 9,
                    name: 'LA Tech Summit',
                    location: 'Los Angeles, CA',
                    startDate: new Date(currentYear, 10, 17),
                    endDate: new Date(currentYear, 10, 17)
                }
            ]
        });
        
        $('#save-event').click(function() {
            saveEvent();
        });
    });
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.bootstrap-year-calendar.com/css/bootstrap-year-calendar.min.css">
    <title>Calendar</title>
  </head>
  <body>    
    <div id="calendar" class="calendar" data-provide="calendar"></div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <div id="event-modal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title">Evento</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ID" name="event-id" value="" id="event-id">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Evento" name="event-name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Local" name="event-location">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Evento" name="event-start-date">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Local" name="event-end-date">
                </div>
            </form>            
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="save-event">Salvar Evento</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://www.bootstrap-year-calendar.com/js/bootstrap-year-calendar.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.bootstrap-year-calendar.com/download/languages/bootstrap-year-calendar.pt.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.bootstrap-year-calendar.com/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Obrigado querido !
Consegui resolver de outra forma !
Posso compartilhar o código se quiserem !